# Max & AVG MYSQL INNER JOIN for 2 tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 tables (example):

users:

```
ID    company_ID
1     7
2     6
3     7
```

activity_rewards:

```
user_ID    points    activity_type_ID
1          1         7
1          2         7
1          1         7
1          1         8
2          1         7
2          1         7
2          2         8
2          1         7
3          2         7
3          1         7
3          2         8
3          1         8
```

(There are also tables for company and activity_types, but they shouldn't be relevant here)

I need a MYSQL query that will sum the total points for each user `WHERE` all users have a certain `company_ID` and for a certain `activity_type_ID` AND it will return the `MAX` and the `AVG` of the sum of all the users points

I have for example:

```
SELECT SUM(activity_rewards.points) AS totalpoints, 
  MAX(activity_rewards.points) AS maxpoints, 
  AVG(activity_rewards.points) AS avgpoints 
FROM activity_rewards
INNER JOIN users 
  ON activity_rewards.user_ID = users.ID 
WHERE ( (users.company_ID = "7") && (activity_rewards.activity_type_ID LIKE '8') )
```

In the example query only 3 results are involved.  They are:

```
user_ID    points    activity_type_ID
1          1         8
3          2         8
3          1         8
```

I want to get:

- user 1 has 1 point
- user 3 has 3 points
- Max is 3 average is 2

instead I'm getting Max is 2 and average is 1.33

Comment: You want the max and the average of the points summed by user id then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are in line with your query, but your query is not in line with your requirements.

Your query calculates the max and the average of points across the relevant records. But you seem to want the max and the average of the points summed by user id.

This means that you need to calculate the sum of points per user in a subquery and then calculate the max and average in the outer query.

```
SELECT SUM(sumpoints) as totalpoints, max(sumpoints) as maxpoints, avg(sumpoints) as avgpoints
FROM
    (SELECT users.ID, SUM(activity_rewards.points) AS sumpoints
    FROM activity_rewards
    INNER JOIN users ON activity_rewards.user_ID = users.ID 
    WHERE users.company_ID = 7 and activity_rewards.activity_type_ID = 8
    GROUP BY users.ID) t
```

Comment: Thank you this worked.  Can you tell me what the "t" at the end signifies?

Comment: It as an alias, similarly to totalpoints, maxpoints, and avgpoints (the use of `as` is optional). Each derived table (subquery in the `from` clause) has to have an alias (a name).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
SELECT MAX(sum_points) max, AVG(sum_points) avg, SUM(sum_points) sum_all FROM (SELECT SUM(t2.points) sum_points FROM users t1 JOIN activity_rewards t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.user_ID) WHERE ( (t1.company_ID = "7") AND (t2.activity_type_ID = '8') ) GROUP by t1.ID) as summation
```